# Updating web app in ASP .NET CORE Replaces files, or Deletes files, how to keep file in app, when updating

Tags: c#, linux, visual-studio, docker, .net-core

I'm using XML file in my project, where i store some info. 
Problem is my project is live, and I am periodically updating it, when I publish new version that file gets replaced, or deleted.

in Visual Studio
If I choose Copy to output directory:"Do not copy", it get's removed, if i choose: "always copy" it gets updated, is there a way to update app, but to leave that file same as it was.

I'm Using Visual studio 2017 Community, ASP .NET CORE 2.1, It's running on Linux server, via DOCKER.

thanks, for help!

**-UPDATE-**

to (Prakash G. R.) anwser:

[Folder profile does have this option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xu1Yz.png) but, not [Docker image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggADZ.png), or am I missing something?, If not I think solution has something to do with  <strike>dockerfile</strike> 
 Volumes?.

Comment: Why are you concerned about how your project builds/deploys this content file? End if the day, your app in the docker container will leverage this file.Copy always creates a new file, yes... but it should be of the same content.

Comment: @brandonhein I think you missed the bit where OP is using it to store live data. So the app is updating it compared to the version which gets deployed, and this is causing data loss. If the content of the file was never changed, there would be no issue, and this question would not be asked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have found solution**.
You need to use Docker volumes for that.
I'm using [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/) as host, so I added a <strike>space</strike> Volume to my droplet, and am now trying to get docker volume inside Digital oceans volume, but I'm having trouble to make it to make work with my app. I should be able to update my web app as much as I want and it will not reset or delete files in volume.

**The short answer is use docker volumes,** the volumes is operating outside of container, so they don't reset files in them on updates.

*I can't get docker volume running on my app, though. I'v created another question about that, see [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56286699/how-to-create-and-use-docker-volumes-on-asp-core-web-app-mvc)*

Answer (score 0):

1. Choose "Do not copy" in Visual Studio, so that the Web Deploy will
   not copy to the Server
2. In the Publish Profile, you need to uncheck the "Remove additional
   files at the destination" option under the "File Publish Options".
   Otherwise, it will remove the file on the server. Unchecking this
   option will leave the additional files (which are not being copied,
   but exists on the Server) will be untouched by Web Deploy

.

Comment: When publishing to docker as image it does not let me have that kind of configuration, I'll update Q, with images, maybe I'm missing something, If not I think solution is somewhere in dockerfile.